# eMail enforces AAAA DNS Record and won't send without

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, email, citadel

I have a problem with a mailserver.

I set up an A and a MX record, I am able to receive mails from different servers, but all outbound mails (to different mail providers) fail with the status:

> 1) Connection failure: Connection broken during SMTP conversation
>   while talking to mx-ha03.web.de;
>
> 2) AAAA-lookup mx-ha03.web.de - DNS server returned answer with no data;
>
> 3) Connection failure: Connection broken during SMTP conversation while talking to mx-ha02.web.de;
>
> 4) AAAA-lookup mx-ha02.web.de - DNS server returned answer with no data;
>
> 5) AAAA-lookup mx-ha02.web.de - DNS server returned answer with no data;

If I dig @8.8.8.8 from the server for mx-ha02.web.de the AAAA record only returns me the SOA.

I am not really sure what's the problem, but my guess is, that the mailserver somehow tries to enforce ipv6 and therefore looks for an AAAA DNS Record.

I have an MX record to my mail.domain.tld and an A record from mail.domain.tld to my public IP Address. And forwarded the smtp / imap ports via iptables.
I set up a fitting DNS in /etc/resolve.conf, I disabled IPv6 for the machine and I configured Citadel to only use IPv4.

Why does it still enforce an quad A DNS record which is solely for IPv6? Or do I greatly misinterpret something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's an accurate read of the problem. These two errors are far more glaring:

> 1) Connection failure: Connection broken during SMTP conversation while talking to mx-ha03.web.de;
>
> 3) Connection failure: Connection broken during SMTP conversation while talking to mx-ha02.web.de;

This indicates that the SMTP conversation itself is breaking down, and implies that it was at least able to *initiate* the connection. Your best next step is to use packet captures to study what is happening during these SMTP transactions from a network level. I would ignore the warnings about absent AAAA records until you can make those two errors go away.

Comment: You were totally right, with tcpdump I could track down that the outbound SMTP connections were interrupted before they could reach the WWW.